# Call Back After Giving Rating to app on PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play, rating

I am able to redirect the user to PlayStore with the screen of my application using the following code to give the rating and Review

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try { 
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

But, please give/suggest the way how I can know that Has user Given Rating or not?
Thanks in Advance for your help

Comment: startActivityForResult  ?

Comment: Okay, then what should I check inside onActivityResult() to know about user has given the rating or not ?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, please give/suggest the way how I can know that Has user Given Rating or not?

There's no callback or similar mechanism for this.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, Do you know any way to post Rating and Review from application Directly using any other API/Library?

Comment: No and I doubt this would be allowed because it'd give you the possibility to modify the rating/review before it's posted.

Comment: Another thing is would it be worth cheating your users only for better rating. Eventually this would be easy to discover for them on app site in Play Store.  In contrast spamming using such a mechanism would be a threat indeed.

Comment: Okay, I got your Point, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's impossible. There's no official Google API for Play Store. However there are some attempts which let you do some bacis things like retrieve comments using an app ID. Check [AndroidMarketAPI](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).

Comment: Michal Thanks for your Answer, I have gone through the AndroidMarketAPI, Still, I am unable check the Rating given by the user or not.
Do you if about any API or Library that let me post the Rating/Review from the application Directly without opening PlayStore. Thanks

Comment: Another issue about this approach is that there's no general way to retrieve ratings without a comment because they do not appear on the app page.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know any. Moreover it's highly improbable that is possible. As you can imagine this would create possibility to post rating and review of an app without any interference of 'real' users. To sum up - you should rethink your app flow.